# Mautic hook is not called (ON_SENT_EMAIL_TO_USER)

Tags: php, mautic

I am writing a plug-on that should add an (dynamic) attachment to the email that is send to the end user. But I am stuck on one thing.

Firstly I was using the `EMAIL_ON_SEND` hook to add an attachment to the email. But it seems that it will add a attachment to each email everytime it is called.

For each email it is called two times. So to the first mail it will add 2 attachments and for the second one 4, etc etc.

The second approach was to use the `ON_SENT_EMAIL_TO_USER` hook. But this one does not seems to be called before the email (in a segment) is send.

```
class EmailSubscriber extends CommonSubscriber
{
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(IntegrationHelper $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->parser = new ApiParser();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
          //  EmailEvents::EMAIL_ON_SEND => ['onEmailSend', 100],
            EmailEvents::ON_SENT_EMAIL_TO_USER => ['onEmailSend', 100],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Search and replace tokens with content
     *
     * @param EmailSendEvent $event
     */

    public function onEmailSend(EmailSendEvent $event)
    {
        error_log('123');
    }
```

Someway I have to hook on the actual action that is sending the email instead of the event (?). But I can't figure out which one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Firstly thank you for the response.

The hook is called multiple times so I needed to tweak it.
So we track where it is called and filter it.
Besides that we need to clean the attachments every time.

Anyway even if it is not that clean, it does the trick

```
$trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 5);

            if (strpos($trace[4]['file'], 'SendEmailToContact.php') !== false) {
                $helper = $event->getHelper();

                $messageChildren = $helper->message->getChildren();

                if (count($messageChildren) > 0) {
                    $helper->message->detach($messageChildren[0]);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer directly but might be able to point you at some useful resources!

Firstly, are you trying to send the email to the Mautic user (e.g. the administrator or the owner of the lead), or to the lead? Just wanted to double check we're looking at the right thing as they are often confused!

It also depends on what you're trying to do, attach a file which isn't currently part of Mautic (e.g. an invoice or something like that) or if you're trying to attach a file which you want to track in Mautic as an asset.

In terms of attachments, these resources from the developer documentation may be useful:

- Mailhelper - https://developer.mautic.org/#mail-helper
- Attachments - https://developer.mautic.org/#attachments

It references attachFile() but there is also attachAsset() which allows you to attach a Mautic asset you have already uploaded (\Mautic\AssetBundle\Entity\Asset).

You may also want to take a look at https://forums.mautic.org where there may be more developers from the community able to give some further insight!